# difference between Geology and Geography Data Type MSSQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, geolocation, spatial

SQL server introduced new data type for Geological information,but i am not being able to understand the exact difference between Geometry and Geography data type ..

can any one clarify it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Geology data type. Where did you get this idea from? :)

New data types introduced since 2008 are called `spatial`. 
In general, spatial data types are `geometry` which can be used to store "flat" shapes definitions, and `geography` for geographic coordinates.

You can read more about it here:
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=226407